# sqlcmd new login/user

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am  new to sqlcmd and I want to create a new user. I have done the following:

```
1> CREATE LOGIN FYI_DBA WITH PASSWORD = 'V_2017'
2> go
1> CREATE USER FYI_DBA FOR LOGIN FYI_DBA
2> go
```

Then from cmd prompt I ran  the following:

```
sqlcmd -s LOCALHOST -U 'FYI_DBA' -P 'V_2017'
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user ''FYI_DBA''..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see in the SQL error log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that your SQL Server allows SQL authentication. By default it will be windows authentication only. You can check the SQL Server errorlog which will provide the login failure reason.

The message I you would see in the log in that situation would be

> Login failed for user 'FYI_DBA'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL
>   authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication
>   only. [CLIENT: ]

You can change the authentication type using the [GUI or T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode)

Comment: Besides what Nic mentioned above you also have to what @Tara Kizer mentioned in other answer. Remove single quotes. I just test it. Are you sure that login and user got created? I am asking because you are using a weak password.

Comment: This did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Remove the single quotes around the values for -U and -P.

> sqlcmd -s LOCALHOST -U FYI_DBA -P V_2017

Comment: I ran the above command, I got the same exact error

Comment: See Nic's answer then.

Comment: @Tara Kizer you were right. Will need to do both or login did not get created  due weak password?

Comment: SqlWorldWide you are absolutly right. I had to do what Nic suggested then I had to remove the quotation as Tara suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you ar emissing the trailing semicolon `;` at the end of the SQL statements.

That is not needed at the end of the `go` predicate that sends the command to the server for actual execution.

So, your commands should look like this:

```
1> CREATE LOGIN FYI_DBA WITH PASSWORD = 'V_2017';
2> go
1> CREATE USER FYI_DBA FOR LOGIN FYI_DBA;
2> go
```

Then, to clear any doubt about quotes, login names, user names, role names and schema names are SQL IDs and don't require any quoting (unless you are using some special characters). On the other side, the password is a string and requires quoting.

Finally, to validate the newly created credentials, I would suggest something like:

```
sqlcmd -C -S db.hostname.or.ip,1433 -d existing_db -U username -P 'password' -Q  "SELECT 1;"
```

If it succeeds (once you preplaced the relevand bits with actual values), then your credentials are valid.